# Good practice using SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I saw a sassy CSS for a rails app like this:

```
$std-margin: 30px;

@mixin solid-bg($color: #EEEEEE) {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 $color;
}

@mixin solid-border($direction, $width: 1px, $color: black) {
  @if $direction == "" {
    border: {
      color: $color ;
      width: $width;
      style: solid;
    }
  } @else {
    border-#{$direction}: {
      color: $color ;
      width: $width;
      style: solid;
    }
  }
}

html {
  font: 90%/1.3 arial,sans-serif;
  body {
    margin: $std-margin;
    .top-nav {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      .login {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 63px;
        clear: both;
      }
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }
    .content {
      @include solid-border("");
      clear: both;
      padding: 15px;
    }
    h2 {
      margin: $std-margin;
      margin-left: 0px;
    }
    h3, .detail {
      margin: $std-margin;
    }
    #header {
      ul {
        list-style: none outside none;
        padding: 0;
        li {
          float: left;
          a {
            @include solid-bg();
            color: #0000CC;
            display: block;
            padding: 0.24em 1em;
            text-decoration: none;
          }
        }
      }
      #selected a {
        @include solid-bg(white);
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        top: 1px;
        @include solid-border("");
        @include solid-border('bottom', 0px);
      }
    }
    label {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 1em;
      text-align: right;
      width: 10em;
    }
    input {
      @include solid-bg(#FAFAFA);
      -moz-border-radius: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em;
      @include solid-border("", 1px, #DDDDDD);
      font: bold 0.95em arial,sans-serif;
      padding: 0.15em;
      width: 10em;
    }
    .field {
      padding: 5px;
      clear: both;
      input {
        width:12em;
        @include solid-border("", 1px, #006);
        @include solid-bg(#ffc);
        &:hover {
          @include solid-border("");
          @include solid-bg(#ff6);
        }
      }
      .fieldWithErrors {
        float: left;
        padding: 3px;
        input {
        @extend .field.input;
        @include solid-border("", 2px, red);
        }
      }
      .create {
        width:5em;
      }
      .submit {
        @include solid-bg(#D0DAFD);
        border: 0 none;
        cursor: pointer !important;
        display: block;
        height: 26px;
        margin: 1em;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 69px;
      }
    }

    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      margin: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 480px;
      font {
       family: "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Sans-Serif;
       size: 12px;
      }
      th {
        @include solid-bg(#B9C9FE);
        @include solid-border('bottom', 1px, #FFFFFF);
        @include solid-border('top', 4px, #AABCFE);
        color: #003399;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: normal;
        padding: 8px;
      }
      tr {
        @include solid-bg(#E8EDFF);
        &:hover td {
          @include solid-bg(#D0DAFD);
          color: #333399;
        }
        td.title {
         color: #333399;
        }
      }
      td {
        @include solid-border('bottom', 1px, #FFFFFF);
        @include solid-border('top', 1px, transparent);
        color: #666699;
        padding: 8px;
      }
    }
    .activities {
      padding: 10px;
      a{
        margin: 10px;
      }
    }
    .flash {
      font-family:'Trebuchet MS';
      color:#FF0000;
      font-size:14px;
    }
    .calendar_date_select table {
      width: 78px;
      td {
        padding: 5px;
      }
    }
    .main-content {
      clear: both;
      float: left;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }
    #errorExplanation {
      @include solid-bg();
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 5px 0 5px 20px;
    }
  }
}
```

Using best practice how this can be optimized?

Comment: Optimization usually depends on the HTML. Can you provide it with use cases for all the rules? Also could you point out the advantages you see in your mixins over just using `background-color` and `border` directly?

Comment: @RoToRa: I am learning about sassy css and I saw this for some rails application. I don't know why those hav been used. As far as i understand mixins are used to replace a set of common style, and they might have used mixin for background as all the background differs only in color and have same value for the properties position, repeat and scroll. I am not sure why they have used. Its purely my guess.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is [not code written by you](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/why-is-only-my-own-written-code-on-topic)

Answer (score 8):

One optimization you should do in any case is not to have all rules inside `html { ... }` and `body { ... }`, because the resulting CSS rules all require the renderer to unnecessarily check every single element if it is actually a decedent of `html` and `body` - which they undoubtedly are.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, that code would best be optimized by *removing* the mixins.  They're not saving you any typing *and* generating highly inefficient CSS.  Using proper CSS shorthand would help too.

From the solid background mixin:

```
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 $color;
```

vs

```
background: $color;
```

Shorter to write, shorter when compiled.

---

From the border mixin:

```
border: {
  color: $color ;
  width: $width;
  style: solid;
}
```

vs

```
border: $width solid $color;
// or just `$width solid` if the border will be the same color as your text
```

---

There's an instance of `cursor: pointer` without `cursor: hand` to go with it (some browsers use one, others use the other)

---

```
  font {
   family: "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Sans-Serif;
   size: 12px;
  }
```

vs

```
font: 12px "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Sans-Serif;
```

---

There's a lonely border-radius property with *only* the -moz- prefix, not even the non-prefixed version to go with it.

---

The table styles are all nested unnecessarily

- `table tr`
- `table tr td.title`
- `table td`

The tr and td elements cannot appear outside of tables, so saying it must be a descendant of a table is superfluous.  Similarly, td must be a descendant of tr, so again redundancy.